# Function "onButtonClicked" is never use

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have created a function called "onButtonClicked" and I want the button (bt301_tw) to send me to the activity (MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup).

The problem is when I create the function onButtonClicked, I can't use it and I don't want to use a setOnClickListener because I'm practicing with different views

My code:

XML

```
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt301_tw"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorActivatedHighlight"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/rodiogroup_301" />
```

Mainactivity

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view.id == R.id.bt301_tw) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) 
       }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can supress the warning using `@Suppress("unused")` annotation above your function. Compilers aren't that intelligent that they will parse the xml structure, and it is generally a good practise to put lifecycle code in your Kotlin/Java codebase instead of XML.

Comment: The problen is i can't use the function

Comment: You have to specify Activity for that in top-level XML structure like in your Layout `tools:context="com.example.sample.MainActivity"`

Comment: What are you trying to do with this function? If you don't use it you can delete it (or keep it there with the warning). If you're using it, the warning will disappear.

Comment: I want that when I press the button (bt301_tw), it sends me to the activity (MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works for me:

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.bt301_tw)) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
            startActivity(intent) 
       }
    }
```

If you are using data binding then you can directly mention view name:

```
fun onButtonClicked(view: View) {
    if (view.id == bt301_tw) {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity_04_ReadioGroup::class.java)
        startActivity(intent) 
   }
}
```

Hope this helps

Just to add **view.id == R.id.bt301_tw**
This will never be same.

Comment: this worked for me (view == findViewById(R.id.bt301_tw))